# TableView Array Map

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My code is `swift 3` and has create two array in `TableView`, get JSON data into `Array`, if I map this two array will get error index out of range, How to right map `Array` ?

```
func trainType() {
    do {
        /// 取得所有列車車種資料
        let trainTypeUrl = URL(string: "http://ptx.transportdata.tw/MOTC/v2/Rail/TRA/TrainClassification?$format=JSON")

        let trainTypeData = try? Data(contentsOf: trainTypeUrl!)
        let trainTypeJson = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: trainTypeData!, options: .mutableContainers)

        if let trainTypes = trainTypeJson as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
            for dataTrainType in trainTypes {


                trainTypeArray.append(dataTrainType as AnyObject)
            }
        }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func trainInOutstatusData() {
    do {

        let trainStatusUrl = URL(string: "http://ptx.transportdata.tw/MOTC/v2/Rail/TRA/LiveBoard?$format=JSON")

        let trainInOutstatusData = try? Data(contentsOf: trainStatusUrl!)
        let trainInOutStatusjson = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: trainInOutstatusData!, options: .mutableContainers)
        if let InOutStatus = trainInOutStatusjson as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
            for dataInOutStatus in InOutStatus {

                trainStatusArray.append(dataInOutStatus as AnyObject!)

            }
        }

    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

map array

```
let stationClassID = trainStatusArray[indexPath.row]["TrainClassificationID"] as? String
    let trainClassID = trainTypeArray[indexPath.row]["TrainClassificationID"] as? String
    if stationClassID == trainClassID {
        if let trainTypeID = trainTypeArray[indexPath.row]["TrainClassificationID"] as? [String : Any] {
            let ZHtw = trainTypeID["Zh_tw"] as? String
            cell.stationTrainClassID.text = ZHtw

        }
    }
```

Comment: Before matching the value from both array, check for the count of both arrays. Do you have same number of data in both arrays?

Comment: this two array size is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have different data counts in both array, you can't do as you tried. Because consider you have **5 count in trainStatusArray** and **3 count trainTypeArray**, your **current indexPath.row is 4**. Then

```
let stationClassID = trainStatusArray[4]["TrainClassificationID"] as? String // You will get some value here.
let trainClassID = trainTypeArray[4]["TrainClassificationID"] as? String // Here app will crash because, total count is 3 in but you are trying to access element at index 4.
```

**Solution:**

You can give an array which have higher count as data source to `tableView`, then you can use `for loop` in `cellForRowAtIndexpath` to check the values are matching or not.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let stationClassID = trainStatusArray[indexPath.row]["TrainClassificationID"] as? String
    for trainType in trainTypeArray {
        let trainClassID = trainType["TrainClassificationID"] as? String
        if stationClassID == trainClassID {
            if let trainTypeID = trainTypeArray[indexPath.row]["TrainClassificationID"] as? [String : Any] {
                let ZHtw = trainTypeID["Zh_tw"] as? String
                cell.stationTrainClassID.text = ZHtw
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks.